# SwiftUI: Why .prefersDefaultFocus modifier does not receive focus if there is a TabView on tvOS?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, focus, tvos

I am developing a tvOS application and I wanted to use view like split screen of course I need focus management in it. I've seen video from WWDC and my research that this can be done with the `prefersDefaultFocus(_:in:)` modifier. I even made a little demo. While it works fine if TabView is not used on the screen, `prefersDefaultFocus(_:in:)` does not work when `TabView` is added.

Have any of you encountered this situation? How can it be overcome?

Here is my code sample, you can test both case;

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            //ContentView()
            ContentWithTabView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.resetFocus) var resetFocus
    @Namespace private var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 100) {
            Group {
                VStack {
                    Button ("1") {}
                    .prefersDefaultFocus(in: namespace)
                    Button ("2") {}
                    Button ("3") {}
                }}
            
            Group{
                VStack {
                    Button ("1") {}
                    Button ("2") {}
                    Button ("3") {}
                    Button ("Reset to default focus") {
                        resetFocus(in: namespace)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .focusScope(namespace)
    }
}

struct ContentWithTabView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```